# Execution skips lines

Tags: android

I'm really stumped by this one:

Code execution jumps from line 07 to line 10. What the heck Java? Skipping line 08 and "falling through" the if statement???

```
01    public String getContainerNameFromUID(Activity aActivity, Long aUID, String aDefault){
02        if(aUID != null){
03            Cursor containerCursor;
04            containerCursor = fetchContainer(aUID);
05            aActivity.startManagingCursor(containerCursor);
06            int i = containerCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_NAME);
07            String test =containerCursor.getString(i);
08            return test;
09        }else{
10            return "Null";
11        }
12    }
```

Comment: Are you seeing execution "jumping" in a debugger?  Because that often means there's a problem with debugging, for example, your compiled Java is not the same version as the source, so the line numbers don't line up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler has probably optimised the code to avoid the redundant locally-scoped assignment.

Comment: Thanks guys, looks right. Stepping through the code in eclipse makes it appear that the code execution skips to the last return statement, but this is an illusion. I guess it is because of compiler optimization. The code is working properly; **test** is being returned, not "Null."